# Assigning a static IP on HP-UX

Tags: static-ip, hp-ux

I can't find how to set a static IP on the local network (192.168.xxx.xxx) on HP-UX using the command line.  I want the address to be kept after the server reboots, so it seems the use of `ifconfig` will lose the IP configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way for a novice is to use SAM -> Network Configuration.  However, since you have stated you want to use the command line, use set_parms:

`# set_parms ip_address`

Alternatively edit /etc/rc.config.d/netconf and /etc/hosts manually.

See man set_parms for more information.